# Effect of temperature on density of states effective mass

Tags: density-functional-theory, density-of-states

The experimental study shows that Density of state effective mass is calculated at 300K while in theoretical study DFT yield Density of state effective mass at 0K. Why there is so much temperature difference between both and how this is reasonable?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided more details. At the moment you don't explain what "so much" means, so it is impossible to gauge what the difference may be due to without knowing its magnitude.

Comment: I agree with ProfM, please edit the question to make it descriptive of what you want to ask. Quote relevant references (if any) and try to explain what you have already interpreted (if you have).